# Pairwise Elements Using Python - Calculating Average of individual elements of array

Tags: python, json, for-loop, multidimensional-array

So I have a query; I am accessing an API that gives the following response:

> [["22014",201939,"0021401229","APR 15 2015",Team1 vs. Team2","W",
>   19,4,10,0.4,2,4,0.5,0,0,0,2,2,4,7,5,0,2,1,10,14,1],["22014",201939,"0021401","APR
>   13 2015",Team1 vs. Team3","W",
>   15,4,13,0.4,2,8,0.5,0,0,0,2,2,4,7,5,0,8,1,12,14,1],["22014",201939,"0021401192","APR
>   11 2015",Team1 vs. Team4","W",
>   22,5,10,0.4,2,6,0.5,0,0,0,2,2,4,7,5,0,2,1,8,14,1]]

I could just as easily have 16 different variables that I assign zero to, then print them out like the following example:

```
sum_pts = 0

for n in range(0,len(shot_data)): #range of games; these lengths vary per player
       sum_pts= sum_pts+float(json.dumps(shots_array[n][24]))
print sum_pts/float(len(shots_array))
```

Output:

```
>>> 
23.75
```

But I'd rather not create 16 different variables that calculate the average of the individual elements in this list. I'm looking for an easier way that I could get the average of Team1

I would like it the output to eventually be, so that I can apply this to infinite number of players or individual stats:

```
Team1 AVGPTS AVGAST AVGSTL AVGREB...
      23.75  5.3    2.1    3.2
```

Or it could be:

```
  Player1 AVGPTS  AVGAST  AVGSTL AVGREB   ...
          23.75    5.3     2.1    3.2 ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the averages of the last 16 entries of each entry, you could use the following approach, this avoids the need to define multiple variables for each column:

```
data = [
    ["22014",201939,"0021401229","APR 15 2015", "Team1 vs. Team2","W", 19,4,10,0.4,2,4,0.5,0,0,0,2,2,4,7,5,0,2,1,10,14,1],
    ["22014",201939,"0021401","APR 13 2015","Team1 vs. Team3","W", 15,4,13,0.4,2,8,0.5,0,0,0,2,2,4,7,5,0,8,1,12,14,1],
    ["22014",201939,"0021401192","APR 11 2015","Team1 vs. Team4","W", 22,5,10,0.4,2,6,0.5,0,0,0,2,2,4,7,5,0,2,1,8,14,1]]

length = float(len(data))
values = []

for entry in data:
    values.append(entry[6:])

values = zip(*values)
averages = [sum(v) / length for v in values]

for col in averages:
    print "{:.2f} ".format(col),
```

This would display:

```
18.67  4.33  11.00  0.40  2.00  6.00  0.50  0.00  0.00  0.00  2.00  2.00  4.00  7.00  5.00  0.00  4.00  1.00  10.00  14.00  1.00
```

Note, your data is missing an opening quote before each `Team1 vs Team2`.

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked after some minor manipulation!!! Now if I can understand what's going on/be on your level of programming knowledge.

Comment: Glad it worked for you, `print` is your friend, I suggest you print out `values` after the `for` loop and after the `zip` and hopefully you'll see how it works.